# How to test function that requires user input in command line using mocha, chai, and robotjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to unit test this function with mocha, chai, and robotjs. I am currently able to get robotjs to input data, but I am not able to test this function by itself. Right now my terminal is saying that I expected {} to equal 'https://toscrape.com/'. 'https://toscrape.com/' is the baseurl used in this function, and if the user types no, this should be returned. An object is returned from another function later down the line. How do I test this function?

```
// allow user to input a url and then validate url
const requestSiteURL = async function () {
  let url = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    readline.question('Please type url: ', resolve);
  });
  let URL = 'https://toscrape.com/';
  if (validUrl.isUri(url)) {
    readline.close();
    return url;
  } else if (url.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
    url = URL;
    return url;
  } else {
    console.log(
      'Please type in a valid URL (https://toscrape.com/) or type "no" to use base url.'
    );
    return requestSiteURL();
  }
};
```

here is my test case so far

```
const url = require('../crawler');
const robot = require('robotjs');
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

var roboInput = () => {
  robot.typeString('no');
  robot.keyTap('enter');
};

describe('validates site url', function () {
  it('no', function () {
    roboInput();
    let result = url.requestSiteURL();
    expect(result).to.equal('https://toscrape.com/');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to write unit tests, so you need to test your code in an isolated, side-effect-free environment. In order to provide such an environment, it is necessary to create stubs or mocks for modules and methods with side effects. Here I will use [sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/), because it is often used in conjunction with the `mocha` test framework and the `chai` assertion library.

What is an isolated environment? For your example, we don’t need users or `robotjs` automation scripts to really enter text in the terminal.

For your case, we should create stubs for `readline.question()`, `readline.close()` etc..

E.g.

`crawler.js`:

```js
const rl = require('readline');

const validUrl = {
  isUri(url) {
    return url === 'https://toscrape.com/';
  },
};
const readline = rl.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

const requestSiteURL = async function() {
  let url = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    readline.question('Please type url: ', resolve);
  });
  let URL = 'https://toscrape.com/';
  if (validUrl.isUri(url)) {
    readline.close();
    return url;
  } else if (url.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
    url = URL;
    return url;
  } else {
    console.log('Please type in a valid URL (https://toscrape.com/) or type "no" to use base url.');
    return requestSiteURL();
  }
};

module.exports = { requestSiteURL };
```

`crawler.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const readline = require('readline');
const expect = chai.expect;

function resetModules() {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./crawler')];
}

describe('65298539', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    resetModules();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should return url if it is valid', async () => {
    const readlineInterfaceStub = {
      question: sinon.stub().callsFake((query, callback) => {
        callback('https://toscrape.com/');
      }),
      close: sinon.stub(),
    };
    sinon.stub(readline, 'createInterface').returns(readlineInterfaceStub);
    const url = require('./crawler');
    const actual = await url.requestSiteURL();
    expect(actual).to.be.eql('https://toscrape.com/');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(readlineInterfaceStub.question, 'Please type url: ', sinon.match.func);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(readlineInterfaceStub.close);
  });

  it('should set default url if user enter "no"', async () => {
    const readlineInterfaceStub = {
      question: sinon.stub().callsFake((query, callback) => {
        callback('No');
      }),
    };
    sinon.stub(readline, 'createInterface').returns(readlineInterfaceStub);
    const url = require('./crawler');
    const actual = await url.requestSiteURL();
    expect(actual).to.be.eql('https://toscrape.com/');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(readlineInterfaceStub.question, 'Please type url: ', sinon.match.func);
  });

  it('should recursive call', async () => {
    let callCount = 0;
    const readlineInterfaceStub = {
      question: sinon.stub().callsFake((query, callback) => {
        if (callCount === 0) {
          callCount++;
          callback('');
        } else {
          callback('No');
        }
      }),
    };
    sinon.stub(readline, 'createInterface').returns(readlineInterfaceStub);
    sinon.spy(console, 'log');

    const url = require('./crawler');
    const actual = await url.requestSiteURL();
    expect(actual).to.be.eql('https://toscrape.com/');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(readlineInterfaceStub.question, 'Please type url: ', sinon.match.func);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(
      console.log,
      'Please type in a valid URL (https://toscrape.com/) or type "no" to use base url.',
    );
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  65298539
    ✓ should return url if it is valid (1516ms)
    ✓ should set default url if user enter "no"
Please type in a valid URL (https://toscrape.com/) or type "no" to use base url.
    ✓ should recursive call


  3 passing (2s)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 crawler.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```